# httpd: bad user name apache

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos, httpd, centos-5

on centos when I enter

`service httpd start` or `restart`

server gives

```
Starting httpd: httpd: bad user name apache
                                                           [FAILED]
```

I tried to add apache user and group, reinstalled httpd so many times but it did not worked either.

Comment: when you tried to create apache user were you able to create it? or that failed too?

Comment: I can create the user. Also I checked it from /etc/passwd and /etc/group files

Comment: Try creating it from init. `cd /etc/init.d; sudo ./httpd start` A bit of googling revealed that a lot of people have problems with it overriding the config settings with environment variables.

Comment: I tried this too but it gives the same error :( I googled this error and non of the solutions helped me. I changed file permissions, config file etc :/

Comment: if no solution helps, uninstall and install it again. If still fails, try to build it on your own (not install via yum,.. but build from source)

Comment: This may be what you are looking for:
http://drjohnstechtalk.com/blog/2012/03/major-headaches-migrating-apache-over-from-ubuntu-ato-centos/

Comment: I reinstall via yum so many times. I'll try building from source. thanks.

Comment: Darn!! I can't believe that I made a mistake in group name called it `Www-data` instead of `www-data`... hope this check helps someone...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run config test

```
[root@9001 conf_0.d]# /etc/init.d/httpd configtest
Syntax OK
```

Check what users and group set in httpd.conf

```
User apache
Group apache
```

Disable SELinux if its enabled.

Comment: disabling SELinux solved the problem. thanks a lot =))

Comment: but when I reboot server I have to disable SELinux again. what should I do for this problem ?

Comment: Disable permanently selinux edit /etc/sysconfig/selinux  SELINUX=disabled

Comment: Imo, disabling SELinux is not a good advice. At least explain, why SELinux could cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check your apache entire in below config file

```
/etc/passwd 
/etc/group
```

in Redhat 7 entire should be below

```
/etc/passwd > apache:x:48:48:Apache:/usr/share/httpd:/sbin/nologin
/etc/group > apache:x:48:
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem because the group didnt exist in /etc/group.
I created and it worked